Can't import Next.js Google Font
"TypeError: (0 , next_font_google___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Istok_Web) is not a function"
import { Istok_Web } from "next/font/google/"
const istokWeb = Istok_Web({ weight: "400", subsets: ["latin"], })
<motion.h1
            layoutId={"title-" + project.id}
            className={cn(
              "text-8xl px-8 md:px-20 font-semibold text-white",
              istokWeb.className
            )}
>

it works for the inter font that was there by default (create next app)
i use next 14
I tried to import the font and expected it to work normally.
I did look for simular issues. (only somewhat simular question was using jest and had to mock it)

What if you remove trailing slash from your import?

@Mr.Hedgehog No way this was the solution haha!
